# re.sub() for spaces and tabs

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find 2 `re.sub()` lines. The first one changes any number of spaces and/or tab characters in any order into a space. (Maybe this should be 2 separate ones?)
The second one changes anything that is not a letter or a space into an empty string. I included what I know so far for each one below

```
re.sub("?"," ",word)
re.sub("?","",word)
```

What should be put where the question marks are? Thanks.

Comment: The first `?` would be `\s+`. The second `?` would be `[^a-zA-Z ]`.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

- `\s+` for all whitespace, but watch out for the details
- `[ \t]+` if you only want tabs & spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

word = "hello    this is \ta\ttest"
result = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", word) 

print(result)  # prints: hello this is a test
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
re.sub('\s+', ' ', word)
```